# Getting all result of stored procedure using Larvel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a query like this:

```
$res = DB::select("CALL lending_ewallets_balance_in_merchant(87,165);");
```

As you can see, I'm calling an stored procedure. When I call it directly inside MySQL, it returns two rows, but when I `dd($res)`, it contains just one row. How can I get all rows returned by stored procedure in Laravel?

---

Based on some research, I guess it's possible to do that using PDO by `fetchAll()` method (or loop over `fetch()`). But I want to do that using Laravel.

Comment: `DB::select` should also get all rows. There's no inherent limit on how many rows you'd get

Comment: it shouldn't make a difference how you call the procdure, the result should always be the same. so you cann different parameters is my first guess